# Is is possible to create key-value ComboBox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I know how to create a combobox in Tkinter and how to populate it with an array of strings.

However, I want to associate each string in it with a value so that in a handler of `<<ComboboxSelected>>` I'm able to retrieve it.

How can I do that? I've tried using a dictionary, but it hasn't panned out.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, this should be rather straightforward: Your event handler method can do arbitrary lookups using the currently selected value of the Combobox. If it is not working in this way, you might have to add some code for context in your question.

Comment: "it hasn't panned out" isn't a precise description. It would help if we could see a [mcve]

Comment: `Combobox` can't do it but you can build own widget using `Combobox`

Answer (score 3):

Here I've just used a list for all the items in the options menu widget and defined a dict to map the item to a value.

Whenever you select an item it will print out the corresponding value.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# define keys and mappings
ITEMS = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
MAPPING = {'Item 1' : 1, 'Item 2' : 2, 'Item 3' : 3}

def onSelect(event):
    print(MAPPING[cmb.get()])

root = tk.Tk()

cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, state = 'readonly', values = ITEMS)
cmb.set(ITEMS[0])
cmb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', onSelect)
cmb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If your items will be in alphabetical order then you can remove the list and just use a dict with the following.

```
ITEMS = sorted(list(MAPPING))
```

If you want to use the same function for multiple Comboboxes with differing mappings then you can do the following.

```
def onSelect(event, mapping):
    print(mapping[event.widget.get()])

cmb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda e: onSelect(e, MAPPING))
```

Comment: I know. My question is how to avoid that.

Comment: Your question only says that you tried using a dictionary, not how to do it without a dictionary. Please expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: pass a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

You can build own widget using `Combobox` which will get dictionary and displays dictionary's keys in `Combobox` and returns dictionary's values.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyCombobox(ttk.Combobox):

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **options):

        self.dict = None

        # get dictionary from options and put list of keys
        if 'values' in options:
            if isinstance(options.get('values'), dict):
                self.dict = options.get('values')
                options['values'] = sorted(self.dict.keys())

        # combobox constructor with list of keys
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, **options)

        # assign some function
        self.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.on_select)

    def on_select(self, event):
        print(self.get(), self.get_key(), self.get_value())

    # overwrite `get()` to return `value` instead of `key`
    def get(self):                              
        if self.dict:
            return self.dict[ttk.Combobox.get(self)]
        else:
            return ttk.Combobox.get(self)

    def get_key(self):
        return ttk.Combobox.get(self)

    def get_value(self):                              
        return self.get()

# --- main ---

items = {'Item 1' : 102, 'Item 2' : 102, 'Item 3' : 103}

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text="List").pack()

# combobox working in old way with list
cb = MyCombobox(root, state='readonly', values=list(items))
cb.pack()
cb.set('Item 3')

tk.Label(root, text="Dictionary").pack()

# combobox working in new way with dictionary
cb = MyCombobox(root, state='readonly', values=items)
cb.pack()
cb.set('Item 1')

root.mainloop()
```