# Python + MySQL. How can I pass the ID of a field from a ComboBox to the database?

Tags: python, tkinter, pymysql

I have a Combobox with selected field values from MySQL DB. How to make it so that the field ID is passed to the database instead of its value in the ComboBox?

Here is a request to the database to add a record:

```
    def new_module(self):
    def new_module_add(Event):
    dt = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    with self.con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO modules (version, date, description, common_id) VALUES ('"+str(self.module_entry0.get())+"', '"+dt+"', '"+str(self.module_description.get("1.0", END))+"', '"+module_common.get()+"')")
    self.con.commit()

    print(self.module_common.get())
```

Here is the ComboBox itself:

```
  with self.con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM common_data")
    c = cur.fetchall()



  self.module_common = ttk.Combobox(master=self.new_module,
              text="Engine",
              values = [(c[i][1]) for i in range(len(c))], state='readonly')

  self.module_common.grid(row=7, column=0)
```

I need the value c[i][0], that is, ID. Is it possible to somehow add this variable there to transfer it to the database?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: `combobox` should gives you index of selected element and you should use it to get ID from `c` something like `ID = c[selected][0]`

Comment: preferred (for security reason): `execute("INSERT ... VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (value1, value2, value3))`

Comment: you should learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len())` - it gives more readable code  like `values = [row[1] for row in c]` instead of `values = [(c[i][1]) for i in range(len(c))]`

Answer (score 0):

`comobobox.current()` can give you `index` of selected element and you can use it to get `ID` from list `ID = c[index][0]`

```
index = self.module_common.current()

ID = c[index][0]
```

but it needs to keep `c` as `self.c` to have access in other functions.

---

Minimal working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def run_sql(event):
    #print(event)

    index = cb.current()
    print('index:', index)

    row = c[index]
    print('ID:', row[0])
    
# --- main ---

c = [
  (123, 'A'),
  (124, 'B'),
  (125, 'C'),
]

root = tk.Tk()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=[row[1] for row in c], state='readonly')
cb.pack()
cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", run_sql)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found my old answer which shows how to build own `ComboBox` which gives different value.

[Is is possible to create key-value ComboBox in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369025/1832058)