# Get a value by index when Combobox selected and assign the value to "textvariable" in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and Tkinter. I'm following [Python + MySQL. How can I pass the ID of a field from a ComboBox to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862377/python-mysql-how-can-i-pass-the-id-of-a-field-from-a-combobox-to-the-database) as a guideline to get the value by index.

My Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# --- functions ---

def run_sql(event):
    #print(event)

    index = cb.current()
    # print('index:', index)

    row = c[index]

    print('ID:', row[0])

    print(data.set(row[0]))
    print(cb.set(row[0]))
    
# --- main ---

c = [
  (123, 'A'),
  (124, 'B'),
  (125, 'C'),
]

root = tk.Tk()
data = tk.StringVar()
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=data,values=[row[1] for row in c], state='readonly')
cb.pack()
cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", run_sql)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
ID: 123
None
None
```

I'm looking for a way to get the value of `123` whenever I use `data.set(row[0])` or `cb.set(row[0])` instead of `None`.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a wrapper function

```
def data_set(value):
    data.set(value)
    return [row[1] for row in c if row[0] == value]
```

But that could return multiple values.

A better solution would be:

```
def data_set(index):
    data.set(c[index][0])
    return c[index][1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to Tkinter. Where can I put the better solution in the code? Is there code I need to remove?. Thank you so much.

Comment: The function can be anywhere but should be in the same or an higher scope then where you would like to use it. In your current code you only use it in `run_sql` so you can put `data_set` inside this function or outside (that would be the global scope). Than you can replace `print(data.set(row[0]))` with `print(data_set(row[0])`. I only wrote the function for `data.set(...)`, but for `cb.set(...)` it is basically the same.
Besides of that wrapper functions are not a tkinter concept, they are useful in a lot of cases.