# Restart the Combobox tkinter after clicking a button

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm new to Python and Tkinter. I'm following [Python + MySQL. How can I pass the ID of a field from a ComboBox to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862377/python-mysql-how-can-i-pass-the-id-of-a-field-from-a-combobox-to-the-database) as a guideline to get the value by index. When I click `Submit` button, the `Combobox` still shows the previous value.

My Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def data_set(index):
    index = cb.current()
    data.set(c[index][0])
    
c = [
  (123, 'A'),
  (124, 'B'),
  (125, 'C'),
]

def clear():
  print(data.get())
  # I need the Combobox shows an empty value before clicking the dropdown button.
  
root = tk.Tk()
data = tk.StringVar()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root,values=[row[1] for row in c], state='readonly')
cb.pack()
cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", data_set)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit",command=clear)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The output when choosing `A` and clicking the `Submit` button:

```
123
```

But The Combobox still displays the previous value:

[image: Still display the previous value]

I'm looking for a way like after choosing `A` and clicking the `Submit` button, the output of `123` print to terminal, then the `Combobox` go back to the beginning like below:

[image: The combobox go back to the beginning]

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would use `StringVar` with `textvariable` in `Combobox` then you could set empty string in `StringVar` to reset `Combobox`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

c = [
  (123, 'A'),
  (124, 'B'),
  (125, 'C'),
]

def clear():
    index = cb.current()
    print(data.get())    # A
    print(c[index][0])   # 123
    data.set('')         # reset

root = tk.Tk()
data = tk.StringVar(root)

cb = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=data, values=[row[1] for row in c], state='readonly')
cb.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=clear)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```